# How to prevent get hasMany relation data when using Custom Query

Tags: php, cakephp, model

A **Purchase** Modal which has **$hasMany** relation.
I can't hide **$hasMany** from Modal because it is needed.

**Problem** : When sometime i am using Custom Query that time i don't want **$hasMany** relation data.

How to prevent get **$hasMany** relation data in **CakePHP** model

What to do in Custom Query to prevent get **$hasMany** relation data.

**Purchase Modal**

```
class Purchase extends AppModel {
      /*
        Modal Related Code
      */

   public $hasMany = array(
        'PurchaseProduct' => array(
            'className' => 'PurchaseProduct',
            'order' => 'PurchaseProduct.created DESC'
        )
    );
);
```

**Purchase Controller** : using a Custom Query here to get only Dates

```
$PurchaseDate= $this->Purchase->find('all',
                                     array('order' =>  array('Purchase.date_generated ASC'),
                                           'fields' => array('DISTINCT Purchase.date_generated','Purchase.id')));
```

**Coming Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 1970-01-01
                    [id] => 9
                )

            [PurchaseProduct] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15
                            [Purchase_id] => 9
                            [product_id] => 5
                            [product_name] => ABC
                            [created] => 2014-08-15 18:51:49
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

**Required Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 1970-01-01
                    [id] => 9
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to prevent hasMany relation data with custom query is to use

```
$this->recursive = -1;
```

you need to define this in model before your query code